# Delete repository that forked from mine

Tags: github

this is serious issue for me. First of all, I am very newbie in github. I thought that I uploaded my school project and assignment files as private. However, I realized that it was public. I check the number of forks. and One people forked mine. I made mine as private, but it seems that he/she still has my repo. Is there anyway that I can delete it? I dont want my homework code to spread into all over the world. 
if I can't, is there any way for me to ask GITHUB company?

Comment: is you can see who did fork?

Comment: it must remove from fork if you can see have a look.

Comment: This is a question for github support.

Comment: @Sulthan That's a silly argument on Stack Overflow. If that's the case, shouldn't every question asking how to perform a function on Github become a question for github support?

Comment: @pipe I am a bit torn. Github support should be the first place to ask and github documentation also describes the problem. We can answer "it's not possible" and we can add multiple paragraphs explaining why but that's not very helpful. The only solution I see is to directly ask the author of the fork to delete it.

Comment: @pipe: No, not every question. Only the ones which are not related to programming. The OP isn't asking how to use the GitHub API to automate releases, for example. I don't see anything even remotely programming-related in this question. Even if the *contents* of that repository were programming-related, the question is not about the content. It could be creative writing assignment, or lab notes from a biology experiment, and it wouldn't change the question one bit. This is a strong indicator that it isn't actually about programming and off-topic on this site.

Comment: It should be obvious that the idea that one user can delete another user's repositories willy-nilly is completely ridiculous. Even on [so], which is explicitly *not* a content repository, deleting another user's content requires democratic agreement of multiple users, can be reverted by democratic agreement of multiple users, and doesn't even actually delete the content, only hide it from low-rep users and display it in a different color for high-rep users. GitHub is among other things a content repository, and thus deleting content must pass a very high bar. Therefore, the fact that …

Comment: GitHub itself must be involved in this, is pretty clear. We cannot do anything about it, only GitHub can. Whether the OP has any grounds to ask GitHub (and make them comply), is a legal question. However, we are not lawyers either. I *did* have law training, and I couldn't even tell you which countries's jurisdictions are relevant here. The OP needs to consult with his lawyer. The only three people or entities that can do something about this, are the owner of the fork, GitHub, and the OP's lawyer, and we are neither.

Comment: Also, nothing can be done about all the clones that are not on GitHub, obviously.

Answer (score 8):

When a public repository is forked and that public repository is made private or deleted, the forked repository still exists but is migrated/moved/owned to one of the fork repositories.  See:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility#changing-a-public-repository-to-a-private-repository

There is little point asking Github to assist.  A fork means that someone took a copy of your repository AND created a new repository that is logically linked to your original repository.  A fork is not the same as a clone.  Anyone could have cloned your repository and they would have a disconnected copy of it and there isn't a thing Github could do to delete that disconnected copy.

By creating a repository with public access, you implicitly agreed to have your code copied.  Maybe you can prevent re-distribution but that would be a case between you and the persons who copied it ... but now we are into the murky waters of code copyright compliance.  This assumes that there was a license file as part of the repository.

Comment: If there wasn't a license file, wouldn't it implicitly be copyrighted and "all right reserved"? Thus giving grounds to demand removal.

Comment: @jpa Nope, by uploading you already grant a license to github and another license to all github users. See github terms and conditions. Quoting **The licenses you grant to us will end when you remove Your Content from our servers, unless other Users have forked it.**.

Comment: @jpa: When you sign up, you agree to the GitHub ToS. This includes, among other things, a clause that by uploading a public repository, you grant the right to read the contents of the repository and to fork it.

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that:

- Deleting a private repository will delete all of its forks.
- Deleting a public repository will not delete its forks.

***Deleting a private repository***

When you delete a private repository, all of its private forks are also deleted.

***Deleting a public repository***

When you delete a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository. All other repositories are forked off of this new parent and subsequent pull requests go to this new parent.

If a private repository is made public and then deleted, its private forks will continue to exist as standalone private repositories in separate networks.

Please go [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/deleting-a-repository) and [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility#changing-a-public-repository-to-a-private-repository) for more details:

I found one [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remove-github-forks) to remove-github-forks.
May it helpful for you

***In last***

In last,you can contact [github support](https://github.com/contact) and ask them to switch your repository to "normal mode".

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is politely contact the person who forked your repository, explain that you published it by mistake and ask if they would make their fork private also.

You can do this by opening a new issue on their fork, which will send a notification to their email.